# MySQL CREATE TABLE 'You have an error in your SQL syntax' error

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064, ddl

I am pulling my hair out over this. I have connected to a MySQL server and am trying to create a table on it:

```
CREATE TABLE order (
    order_id INT,
    order_is_overnight BIT,
    order_quantity INT,
    order_amount DOUBLE,
    order_timestamp DATETIME
);
```

When I run this I get:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (
        order_id INT,
        order_is_overnight BIT,
        order_quantity INT,
        order_amou' at line 1
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
```

This is the world's vaguest error message, akin to a Java exception that says "*Whoops, something went wrong somewhere in your code!*"

Any ideas where I'm going awry?! I have checked, and rechecked, and rechecked and this seems to be a perfectly valid/legal `CREATE TABLE` statement (don't worry about performance, indexes, keys, etc.; this is just a dummy/test table).

Comment: don't forget that ORDER is a reserved word

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHH..... thanks @e4c5 (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is an reserved word, you must enclose it name in back quotes

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
    order_id INT,
    order_is_overnight BIT,
    order_quantity INT,
    order_amount DOUBLE,
    order_timestamp DATETIME
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan C. (+1). FWIW 'order' (in single quotes) did not work, but changing it to **orders** (plural) did. Weird.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word used as this:  `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id`...   BTW fee free to  mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: I will feel free! When SO let's me. You can't accept answers within a certain timeframe of posting a question ;-)